# Can one Application Service call the Application Service from another Bounded Context?

Tags: architecture, domain-driven-design, architectural-patterns

First bounded context: **Requisites**

Here we store user's organization requisites (Title, Logo, ID numbers, Bank requisites)

Second bounded context: **Bank Integration**

Here we have all use cases that somehow connected with integrations with user's banks.

**Use case 1**: User adds new bank account requisites from UI.

`RequisitesApplicationService.AddNewBankAccount(requisitesDTO)`

**Use case 2**: User sets up integration with the bank from UI (Button "Set up integration" near bank account requisites).

`BankIntegrationService.SetUpBankIntegration(bankAccountRequisitesId)`

**Use case 3**: Our app somehow knows about the user's bank account requisites even before the user adds it to the requisites. We want to automatically add known requisites to the app and immediately integrate the account.

**What should I choose?**

1. `BankIntegrationService.AddNewIntegratedBankAccount(requisitesDTO)`?
2. `RequisitesApplicationService.AddNewIntegratedBankAccount(requisitesDTO)`?
3. `var bankAccountRequisitesId = RequisitesApplicationService.AddNewBankAccount(requisitesDTO)`
   and then
   `BankIntegrationService.SetUpBankIntegration(bankAccountRequisitesId)`?
4. Other options?

If 1 or 2 are suitable options, how different Bounded Contexts should talk to each other?

Comment: Are these really two bounded contexts?

Comment: Good question. We decided to split them because the only thing that overlaps is the account's requisites. There are many things that you can do with your organization's requisites in common and the account's requisites in particular. And there are many things that could happen with your bank integration. Even the term "bank account" slightly differs depending on the context.

Comment: I'm going to echo the previous comment and ask why you splitting up the behavior such that there is *any* overlap? Asked another way, if you draw out every single use-case on a sheet of paper, are you sure it's possible to draw two circles such that every use-case is contained in a circle and the circles don't overlap? DDD asks us to *discover* our model through evaluation of our system's intended behavior, not simply *decide* which boundaries exist (and why) according to some holistic appraisal of responsibilities. Your case in particular seems fraught...

Comment: ...any change to account requisites within your `Requisites` context will naturally affect the behavior of your `BankIntegration` context no?

Comment: Ok,  I see what you mean. But what if "Use Case 3" is a new feature that we are going to implement? I mean we've been developing our system with two completely unrelated sets of functionalities: `Requisites` and `BankIntegration`, there were two nonoverlapping circles and then one day we decided to implement some communication between them. If I understand you right, it would mean that now we can't have two bounded contexts though we already could have different teams and other attributes of bounded context.

Comment: I wouldn't describe storing bank account requisites and integrating with bank accounts (using those requisites) as "two completely unrelated sets of functionalities". As I mentioned above, it is a *feature* of your system that any change to bank requisites will *necessarily* affect any integrations using those requisites. That said, I'll take you at your word here and meet you where you are. In this case I would recommend a looser coupling than option 3, integration events. Depending on your architecture this may be an event bus in your application layer or a separate service (like RabbitMQ).